# Elastic search relevance score

Tags: elasticsearch

In a project I'm involved with, Elastic Search is used to contain a couple of million items from a marketplace.

Users can search these items and currently the results returned are sorted by a relevance score based on the number of word occurences.

However the creation time of the items are also highly relevant - so a search for "bike" should return a list of items containing "bike" ordered by how new the item is (newer is more relevant).

I have no hands on with this myself (i'm more frontend than backend) so just need some guidance as to how this can be done? I read something about boosting scores but am unsure on whether that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following structure:

```
"sort" : [
    {
        "YourValue" : {
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }, {  
        "_score" : { }
    }
]
```

Comment: Seems simple - I will take this up with our backend guy :)